# Angular freezes upon ng-include $http.get combination

Tags: angularjs

I have a dynamic template include defined as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div data-ng-include="display()"></div>
```

**Angular**

```
$scope.display = function() {
    var partialTemplate = null;

    $http.get('angular/partials').
        then(function (response) {
            partialTemplate = response.data.path;
        }
    );

    // the 'partialTemplate' variable will be a path for Angular to request the partial file from.
    return partialTemplate;
};
```

This setup freezes the browser unfortunately. Removing the `$http` part and hardcoding a valid path solves this.

Is there any workaround for this while still fetching the partial path from the server (the server decides which partial to return)?

Comment: Well you're returning `null` everytime... `.get` is an async function.

Comment: Some elaboration on a possible solution would be nice... I'm still learning Angular.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The core problem is that the `$http.get` is an async call - so therefore your `return` is being hit before the call completes (that, and you can't `return` from an async call). I'd suggest setting a `$scope` variable and assigning that when the call completes:

```
<div data-ng-include="myTemplate"></div>
```

And the JS:

```
function getTemplate() {
    $http.get('angular/partials').then(function (response) {
        $scope.myTemplate = response.data.path;
    });
}
```

All that's left is to trigger the `getTemplate` function.